# How to link users file selection to a StringSplit

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to get the users chosen file to split into an array which is separated by , and /t.

The user can choose a file at the top of the code but how do I get their choice to split into an array lower down when they press the ValidateButton

The text file or ordered in this way

info,info,info, 
info,info,info, 
info,info,info,

If I can get them into an array then I can easily organises the data.

```
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\"; // Start in C: drive
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Browse Text Files";
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt"; // Extension of file is txt 
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text|*.txt||*.*"; //Only text files 
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FileNameBox.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName; // Chosen file name is displayed in text box

            var fileStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile();

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
                var fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }


    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This is the file path the user has chosen
    }

    public void ValidateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        //Call Multi line text box
        //Call PROGRESS BAR_


        int counter = 0;
        string lines;


        string Patient = lines;

        string[] split = Patient.Split(new Char[] { ',', '\t' });

        foreach (string s in split)


            if (s.Trim() != "")
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            {
                Console.WriteLine(lines);
                counter++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("There were {0} records.", counter);
            Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
List<string> temp = new List<string>();
string[] finalArray;

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
{
    // We read the file then we split it.
    string lines = reader.ReadToEnd();
    string[] splittedArray = lines.Split(',');    

    // We will check here if any of the strings is empty (or just whitespace).
    foreach (string currentString in splittedArray)
    {
        if (currentString.Trim() != "")
        {
            // If the string is not empty then we add to our temporary list.
            temp.Add(currentString);
        }
    }

    // We have our splitted strings in temp List.
    // If you need an array instead of List, you can use ToArray().
    finalArray = temp.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the text will be chosen from a text file and separated by ,  Is there any way to get the users chosen file where you have put string text = "info,info,info\tinfo,info,info\tinfo,info,info";  . So rather than info,info, it is whatever text file the user chooses from above.

Comment: I need to read from a text file that I know will use , to separate the data. The user chooses a file by pressing a button and selecting any text file from the PC. I'm trying to figure out how to get that file they choose to be split into an array using ,  The file will have different data every time but will always have the same layout and be separated by a comma

Comment: @Lizard Sorry for late response. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot, I have been stuck on this for a while.